# Query Importrange does not return any output

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

quick question, please

I want to do a query import range formula in Google Sheets with three criteria:
1: E-mail
2: Number of the week (e.g: 2)
3: The data column

Ive already allowed the sheets to share information but I'm getting a "Query completed with an empty output." message, even thought the cell has an imput.

Formula: =QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("linkofthesheet";"Indicadores!A9:L123");" SELECT Col3 WHERE Col1 = '"&B4&"' AND Col2 = '"&C10&"'")

I was trying before to use a vlookup together with it but a friend told me it would be redundant. Please, what do you guys think it could be the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 2: Number of the week (e.g: 2)

If cell `C10` contains a number, you should leave the `'`quotes`'` out, like this:

`=query( importrange("...put sheet id here..."; "Indicadores!A9:L123"); "select Col3 where Col1 = '" & B4 & "' and Col2 = " & C10, 0)`